# Why std::any & operator= for ValueType is not conditionally noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++17, assignment-operator, any, noexcept

The question is quite simple.

This is the declaration of templated operator= for `std::any`:

```
template<typename ValueType>
any& operator=( ValueType&& rhs );
```

I would expect it to be:

```
template<typename ValueType>
any& operator=( ValueType&& rhs ) noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<std::any>() = std::forward<ValueType>(std::declval<ValueType>()));
```

Namely, if you can copy-assign ValueType to any in a noexcept fashion, then you should be able to have noexcept.

Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The literal answer is that such a specification would be recursive (you're saying the assignment should be `noexcept` if the assignment is `noexcept`).

But the probably more useful answer is that since `any` may have to allocate, you could only really have `noexcept` assignment in the case that `decay_t<ValueType>` is

- sufficiently small (so as to not need allocation), and
- nothrow move constructible, and
- nothrow constructible from `ValueType`

The only way to specify the `noexcept` condition would require you to also specify what "sufficiently small" means - which would limit implementation freedom, for questionable gain.

The standard library doesn't typically use conditional noexcept - so why would this be the... exception?

Answer (score 1):

> `template<class T> any& operator=(T&& rhs);`
>
> **[[any.assign]/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/any#assign-12)** - Throws: Any exception thrown by the selected constructor of VT.

The overload you showed only participate in overload resolution if `ValueType` is copy constructible, which leave the door open for the copy construction of `ValueType` to throw during the `std::any` assignment.

Note that you're also showing a `noexcept` specification defined in terms of the same operation being defined.

Comment: I feel like this doesn't really answer the question. Yes, it is true that `decay_t<ValueType>` has to be copy constructible. So?

Comment: Can an operator be defined `noexcept` even if the effect of it is to throw whatever throws the copy constructor of `T` ?